# Add active class to link (React JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, hyperlink

Have a component that's display menus from array

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory,IndexLink } from 'react-router'

    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "ul.tabs li a" ).first().addClass("current");  

    $("li:not(:first-child)").click(function() {
      $( "ul.tabs li a" ).first().removeClass("current"); 
    });

    });

     function Tabs (props) {

        const numbers = props.menuitems;
      const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
        <li key={number.link} ><Link to={number.link} activeClassName="current" className="tab-link">{number.linkName}</Link></li>
      );
      return (
        <div>
        <ul className="tabs" >{listItems}</ul>
        <div className="tabs-header-stripe"></div>
        </div>
      );

    }
    export default Tabs
```

I added "curent" class by Jquery to first element, the problem is When I go from another page, class not adding, but when I just refresh page It's add normaly.

Answer (score 1):

What you say is happening because the class is added in documentReady event. When yo arrive from another page the event has already been raised but of course the following code cannot find the dom element because it is not present in the page:

```
$( "ul.tabs li a" ).first()
```

What I can suggest is to avoid using jquery (and modifying the dom from outside react) and add the class directly in the react code.
I guess you wanted to do something like this:

```
 import React from 'react'
 import { Link, browserHistory,IndexLink } from 'react-router'

 function Tabs (props) {

    const numbers = props.menuitems;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number, index) =>
    <li key={number.link} ><Link to={number.link} activeClassName="current" className={index === 0 ? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}>{number.linkName}</Link></li>
  );
  return (
    <div>
    <ul className="tabs" >{listItems}</ul>
    <div className="tabs-header-stripe"></div>
    </div>
  );

}
export default Tabs
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133569/discussion-on-answer-by-pinturic-add-active-class-to-link-react-js).